# When handling a Web page request and a 500 error occurs, should I redirect to the error page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, error-handling

I read the following advise by dotnetchris in the comments of a [blog post](http://freshbrewedcode.com/jonathancreamer/2011/11/29/global-handleerrorattribute-in-asp-net-mvc3/) by Jonathan Creamer:

> In a regular application (aka not a RESTful web service), the proper way to handle a 500 error is to issue a 302 temporary redirect, then redirect to the 500 error page that returns a proper 500 status code.

I would like to know if this advise is correct. My experience as a developer is with ASP.NET MVC, and the error handling approaches I have seen relating to that framework are ones where no redirect is issued for a 500 error.

Comment: If the 500 error is being caused by an error in the .htaccess file, wouldn't this cause an infinite redirect loop?

Answer (score 1):

Generally i cant agree with this approach. It's looks like:

-> Access page that return error -> 302 to other page that return 500 error.

It's mean for search bots that this page redirect to other page that return error due to some result. Of course it's not good in this way. In my app i always show errors on the page where they appear. I just change the template of page in this case.